# Why are scams allowed

Tags: fraud

Ok so we know Bitcoin bonus is a scam Why is it allowed to exist I almost fell for it and spent hours trying to figure out what I was supposed to be doing downloading wallet apps and dock apps basically just wasting my time but isn't there some sort of cyber police to stop these crooks because it looks pretty enticing to someone that doesn't know any better and they are out $64 that's BS and nobody does a thing about it pathetic what if that was your mom that fell for it what would you say then

Comment: Why is it allowed by who? Who do you think can make such scams cease existing merely by not allowing them?

Answer (score 2):

### Why does crime exist?

> **Bitcoin bonus is a scam Why is it allowed to exist**

The businesses that provide domain-name registration don't know whether you are registering dollarbonus.com with the aim of providing an honest service or a dishonest one. So long as you pay them they don't care. They may take action if they receive a large number of complaints about a customer's domain they have registered, or about a customer's website hosted on a hosting service they provide.

The US Bureau of Engraving and Printing are responsible for printing dollar bills (banknotes) but they are not consulted by a domain registry in, say, Myanmar, when a business there registers a domain name that includes the word dollar. Furthermore, the US Bureau of Engraving and Printing is not responsible for checking the motives or honesty of businesses in, for example, Myanmar.

I doubt the US Bureau of Engraving and Printing was asked for approval when the car-rental business registered the domain name dollar.com and set up their website. It simply isn't their purpose.

There are many countries that use the word dollar for their different currencies - US dollars, Canadian dollars, Singapore dollar, Caribbean dollar, etc. It would be impractical to consult all the responsible government agencies every time someone tried to use the word dollar as part of a business name or trading name. None of the national agencies responsible for printing various dollars would be interested in vetting such use of the name worldwide.

Bitcoin is essentially a set of ideas that have been made public and an early reference implementation of those ideas that has been used by many different people to make software products. There is no organisation or person in charge of Bitcoin. There is no Bitcoin organisation to check up whether someone in a small town in Ecuador is doing something dishonest using the word bitcoin. Nor is it at all practical for ordinary people like you and I to create such an organisation - it would have insufficient resources to scrutinise the daily activities of 8 billion people and no power to do anything about a suspicious activity the other side of the planet.

A person in France or Japan who occasionally publishes an improvement to one of many Bitcoin wallet projects has no authority over criminals in Myanmar or Ecuador. No more than you do.

Even if you persuaded the domain name registars to ban all use of the word Bitcoin in domain names, criminals would just register  domain names like cryptobonus.com instead and use those to trick people out of money.

---

### Cyber Police

> **isn't there some sort of cyber police to stop these crooks**

Your local police service are likely to have a cybercrime officer or department. Mine do.

---

### Responsibility

> **nobody does a thing about it pathetic**

Combatting crime is primarily the responsibility of your local police.
In a sufficiently civilised society you will be able to ask a local police commissioner what they are doing about cyvbercrime. You would be able to vote in a commissioner who commits to the specific actions you feel are necessary.

Legislating to prevent such crime is primarily the responsibility of your local legislative branch of your national government. In a sufficiently civilised society you will be able to ask your local representative what they are doing about cybercrime, you will be able to vote for a representative who commits to some specific legislative action.

Just as the US Bureau of Engraving and Printing cannot prevent you handing over dollar bills to a con-man on a street corner, the developers of, for example, Bread-wallet cannot prevent you using that wallet to pay someone dishonest.

Taking care when giving cash to strangers is primarily your responsibility. Whether the cash is paper cash or electronic cash.